# C# - Extension property with parameter via static class

Tags: c#

I wanna get user status (online or offline) via `userId` in class `UserState` with property `IsOnline`.

My example code works fine without the first user:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyProgram
{
    public static class User
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, string> OnlineUsers = 
            new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public static void AddOnlineUser(string userId, string name)
        {
            OnlineUsers.Add(userId, name);
        }
    }

    public static class UserState
    {
        public static bool IsOnline
        {
            get
            {
                return CheckingUserOnline(UserInfo.Id);
            }
            set
            {
                IsOnline = value;
            }
        }
        private static bool CheckingUserOnline(string userId)
        {
            var onlineUsers = User.OnlineUsers;
            return onlineUsers.ContainsKey(userId);
        }
    }

    public class UserInfo
    {
        public static string Id { get; set; }
        public UserInfo(string id)
        {
            Id = id;
        }
    }

    public class MainClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            User.OnlineUsers.Add("A101", "King");
            User.OnlineUsers.Add("A102", "Queen");
            User.OnlineUsers.Add("A103", "Jack");

            string[] ids = { "A101", "A103", "A104", "A105", "A102" };
            foreach (string id in ids)
            {
                var user = new UserInfo(id);
                string name = User.OnlineUsers.ContainsKey(id) ?
                   User.OnlineUsers[id] : "N-" + id;

                string status = UserState.IsOnline ? "Online" : "Offline";

                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("User id: {0}.\nName: {1}.\nStatus: {2}",
                    id, name, status));

                Console.WriteLine("_______________\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line `User id:` didn't be printed.

Here is the snapshot:

[image]

That's my problem. Can you give me any idea to fix it?

And 2 small questions are:

- Is property `IsOnline` in class `UserState` called `extension
  property`?
- Object `user` in line `var user = new UserInfo(id);` is never used.
  I've defined it in order to store the current user id. I think it's
  not good for creating a never used variable. Is there another way to 
  set `id` to constructor `public UserInfo(string id){}`?

Thank you!

Comment: did you try also a Console.Writeline("\n") before your user id writeline? (if that solves the user id not displayed? (it ruins the format but would be interesting as it would indicate if there is some display problem or the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: No, there's no such thing as an extension property. An extension method is a static method which is used as if it's an instance method on a different type. In your case, you're not using the instance at all. The fact that your constructor assigns to a *static* field is a huge red flag, btw.

Comment: This might seem like a stupid suggestion but it seems strange that the WriteLine skips a part of the string, so are you sure that you have scrolled the console view all the way up?

Comment: And that the console doesnt just give you a small "view" size? What happens if you have one id less?

Comment: Is this a joke? You just need to scroll upwards one line. The vertical scroll bar in your caption is not at the top position.

Comment: Try printing it to the file , this way you can find the problem is a display problem or not

Comment: @oberheim looking at the window again the press any key message is just the last line that is possible to display......could be that the console window then scrolled automatically for one line without him noticing

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you! And... how about constructor `public UserInfo(string id) {}`. Can you tell me a way to set value to the constructor without defining a new object?

Comment: Thank all. `User id` is my problem with console size.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "set value to the constructor" - but the point of a constructor is to create a new object. I think you really need to take a look at the design again...

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry. I mean that I wanna send an `id` as a parameter to `public UserInfo(string id){}`. In my example, I've defined a new object to do that. But as you see, it is never used.

Comment: Yes, because your design is broken, due to overuse of static fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
public class User
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _onlineUsers = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public static void AddOnlineUser(string userId, string name)
    {
        _onlineUsers.Add(userId, name);
    }
    public static bool IsUserOnline(string userId)
    {
        return _onlineUsers.ContainsKey(userId);
    }
    public static string GetUser(string userId)
    {
        return _onlineUsers[userId];
    }
}

public class UserInfo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public bool IsOnline
    {
        get
        {
            return User.IsUserOnline(this.Id);
        }
    }

    public UserInfo(string id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        User.AddOnlineUser("A101", "King");
        User.AddOnlineUser("A102", "Queen");
        User.AddOnlineUser("A103", "Jack");

        string[] ids = { "A101", "A103", "A104", "A105", "A102" };

        foreach (string id in ids)
        {
            var user = new UserInfo(id);
            string name = User.IsUserOnline(id) ? User.GetUser(id) : "N-" + id;

            string status = user.IsOnline ? "Online" : "Offline";

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("User id: {0}.\nName: {1}.\nStatus: {2}", id, name, status));

            Console.WriteLine("_______________");
        }
    }
}
```

1. Extension Property doesn't exist in C#.
2. I used for you. =P
3. Probably the best reason for why the first line didn't appear is: Too much information on the screen. try to maximize the console window and place the scroll bar at the very beginning.